# Efficiency for non-blocking reading from one descriptor

Tags: c, select, read-write

I develop a C program which monitors for incoming messages from different sources and does stuff according to the messages.
My part is to wait for only one source.
And of course, the wait has to be non-blocking.

What it the most efficiency way to do this ?

1. a non-blocking read() ?
2. a select/poll/epoll way ?

Well, if it is about the same consumed cpu/time, i will choose the simpler option, the read one.
Thanks.

Comment: There is also a method to spawn a separate thread for each source and use blocking `read()`. `most efficiency` - There is no simple answer and I think this question is too broad. I've seen once multiple implementations of the same http server using all possible methods on linux - each of them has different drawbacks (count of clients, size of messages, response time, etc.). It's almost impossible to answer and depends on your architecture (there's also bsd `kqueue()`)  - with some kernel versions one method may be faster then the other.

Comment: If you are waiting on a single source use a blocking read. Non-blocking APIs are for when you have something else to do instead of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

`select` with a timeout on the file descriptor. If your timeout for select is infinite, use a blocking read instead. If your select has a timeout but your program doesn't do anything else, use a blocking read instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using non_blocking read() has some drawbacks:

- When data is coming in very slowly the program will wake up frequently and unnecessarily, which wastes CPU resources.
- When data does come in, the program may not read it immediately if it’s sleeping, so the latency of the program will be poor.
- Handling a large number of file descriptors with this pattern would become cumbersome.

But if your coming data is too small, using select/poll will make system call (`read` for example), to be called lot of times.

For more simple, using select/poll is better, i think.